# Is there a macro around that will let me set a button in Outlook 2010 to set a flag for followup in 3 days?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, tasks, flag

Is there a macro around that will let me set a button in Outlook 2010 to set a flag for followup in 3 days? I can do each task each time under "custom" but this is time consuming. I would really like a button to just reset the flag for followup in 3 days. The options TODAY, TOMORROW, and NEXT WEEK just don't cut it.

Answer (score 1):

**FlagDueBy** was [deprecated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._mailitem.flagdueby%28v=office.12%29.aspx) in Outlook 2007.
It was replaced by **ReminderTime** and **TaskDueDate**.

*Source*: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb610089%28v=office.12%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This will allow you to set any number of days you like.

```
Sub Set_FollowUp()

    Dim numDays As Double
    Dim uPrompt As String
    Dim MyMailItem As Object

    On Error Resume Next
    If ActiveInspector.currentItem.Class = olMail Then
        Set MyMailItem = ActiveInspector.currentItem
    End If

    If MyMailItem Is Nothing Then
    ' Might be in the explorer window

        If (ActiveExplorer.selection.Count = 1) And _
          (ActiveExplorer.selection.Item(1).Class = olMail) Then

            Set MyMailItem = ActiveExplorer.selection.Item(1)

        End If
    End If

    If MyMailItem Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Problem." & vbCr & vbCr & "Try again " & _
         "under one of the following conditions:" & vbCr & _
         "-- You are viewing a single message." & vbCr & _
         "-- You have only one message selected.", _
         vbInformation
        Exit Sub
    End If

    MyMailItem.FlagDueBy = Now + 3

    ' *** optional code ***
    'uPrompt = "Follow-Up how many days from now? Decimals allowed."
    'numDays = InputBox(prompt:=uPrompt, Default:=3)

    'MyMailItem.FlagDueBy = Now + numDays
    'MyMailItem.FlagRequest = "Customized Follow up"
    ' *** end of optional code ***

    MyMailItem.Save

End Sub
```